# Javascript alert appears before <!DOCTYPE> tag

Tags: javascript, virus

I have wordpress 3.5.1 on Debian Squeeze. Every time before the page loads javascript alert appears with message `2819371938193817109948281937271937` and have to click OK to see the page. I get this with every refresh or clicking on some post. I did nothing since the last time when website was working fine. Screenshot:

[image: alert]

The source code:

```
<script>alert("2819371938193817109948281937271937");</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The header.php doesn't have this script and nothing is loading before header.php.

What is happening? 
How can I trace where is the script?

EDIT: I found the script in `wordpress/index.php`, but don't know what put it there. I suspect XML Sitemap plugin.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve. Does it still happen?

Comment: yes, it still happens

Comment: What plugins and themes were you using before it has happened? Are they trustworth? Is your FTP secure?

Comment: Theme: Free WP Tube 4. Plugins: GoCodes, Like dislike counter, To do list, TW Disable Revisions, Wp-PageNavi, WP-PostViews, XML Sitemap.co.uk, my custom. Well, there was no problem before and site is running for 2 months. For FTP you have to know password.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened, but you can locate the script with `grep` command.
I went to `/var/www/` and run `grep -r "2819371938193817109948281937271937" *`

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: this answers the "how can I trace the script" question.